# redux doesn't force mapStateToProps with browserHistory.push()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

For some reason if I try to navigate to a certain URL that's exactly like the current one but has a different query or the same URL without the query
it seems to not detect that it has to mapStateToProps again.
If I run componentWillReceiveProps I can see that React does detect a change(receives the same props that are currently displayed), but redux for some reason doesn't.  Any Ideas what the problem might be?

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        listings: state.mainState.Listings,
        publisher: state.mainState.profilePopUp,
        User: state.mainState.userCookie
    };

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? The props should change and are not changing? Are you not receiving props at all?

Comment: @BravoZulu My component is receiving the same props even though it should render new ones based on the query

Comment: Then you should post your store, if that query triggers an action.. Everything that goes into redux to show why that does not change

Comment: @BravoZulu found some sort of a solution to this, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found some kind of a hackish workaround for this, don't know why it is even necessary in the first place.

Just dispatch an action through componentWillReceiveProps so it forces an update  on your component and have a comparison with some info from the last page so it knows it's not on the same page anymore(query worked for me) and it can stop dispatching over and over.

this solution doesn't look good and is barely understandable if you're not familiar with the code base so I just did my routing another way, hope It helps someone!